# How does a negative power factor look when it is graphed?

Tags: power-factor-correction

How does a negative power factor look when it is graphed? How will this impact apparent power versus true power versus reactive power? And how do we interpret this as per power dissipated versus power absorbed/returned to the system?

Answer (score 1):

THE WEB will answer this instantly if you try searching.

We say power dissipated  is positive when its a load and negative when generated.

Consequently, we say negative PF is generated power with a current phase offset just (as)we say for a load with a positive PF.

Comment: Thank you. That helped me search using better terms than I had been using before giving me more satisfaction and understanding.